# Running a local script with local files as parameters through ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm having a hard time dealing with ssh and bash today. I need to get a script running that has parameters that are local files, running through an ssh connection. Here's the script that handles the ssh connection:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then
    echo "Incorrect number of parameters"
    exit
fi
cat "$3" | while read line; 
do 
    ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 -i ./private_key as@$line < ./mod_users.sh "$1" "$2"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "$line is not accesible" 
    fi
done
```

The "$2" parameter is a local file in the machine I'm doing the ssh from. The script "mod_users.sh" adds or erases a bunch of users that it reads from "$2".

What I'm trying to do is executing the script "mod_users.sh" through ssh, and adding or erasing users in bulk from a network-connected machine. Also, as you can see, all the machines that I would be conneting to have my public key in them, so I'm connecting via a private/public key pair so that the remote machines don't ask for a password.

Hope that's enough information. If you need any extra, just ask for it, I'll be glad to answer.

EDIT: Also, would it be possible to run the script with sudo on the remote machine?

Comment: `ssh ... ./private_key as@$line < ./mod_users.sh "$1" "$2"` is exactly the same as `ssh ... ./private_key as@$line "$1" "$2" <mod_users.sh`, except for being bash-only (POSIX only requires shells to honor redirections at the very end of the line). Is that really what you want (feeding the text of the `mod_users` script as input to your SSH process?)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want, to feed the text and execute it on the remote machine, but using the local files to grab de information

Comment: **Why** does your `mod_users.sh` need to run remotely? If you modified it to do what Sasha assumed you to want in the first place (using the local files to generate remote commands, instead of running commands locally to itself), would that work for your use case? Note that some care is needed to generate remote commands safely in bash -- don't even `echo "useradd $username"`; instead, `printf 'useradd %q\n' "$username"` to ensure that substituted values are safely escaped.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, mod_users.sh and arg $1 are local files, mod_users.sh generates commands for remote machines.

You should do the following:

```
./mod_users.sh "$1" "$2" | ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 -i ./private_key as@$line bash
```

Also you may add sudo to this:

```
./mod_users.sh "$1" "$2" | ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 -i ./private_key as@$line "sudo bash"
```

If you want to do it more secure and to give sudo permissions on particular commands, try this:

```
./mod_users.sh "$1" "$2" | sed 's/^/sudo /'| ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 -i ./private_key as@$line bash
```

It will insert sudo before any line produced by mod_users.sh. But may be the best way is to patch mod_users.sh.

Comment: That won't work. Now it will output an error saying "conditional binary operator expected". I know it has nothing to do with the other script, as it works great on local machines

Comment: Also you should replace $? in line if [ $? -ne 0 ]; You have pipe command, thats why you should use ${PIPESTATUS[1]}. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another

Answer (score 0):

If you change `mod_users.sh` to accept the *text* of your file in `$2`, rather than the *name* of the file, and if your remote user's shell is bash (not `/bin/sh`), you can do this:

```
ssh_args=( -o ConnectTimeout=5 -i ./private_key )
while IFS= read -r line <&3; do 
    printf -v args_q '%q ' "$1" "$(<"$2")"
    if ! ssh "${ssh_args[@]}" "as@$line" "bash -s $args_q" <mod_users.sh; then
        echo "Operation failed for $line" >&2 
    fi
done 3<"$3"
```

If you're not willing to make that change to the file on-disk, you can patch an appropriate prefix into the pipeline:

```
script_prefix='
tempfile=$(mktemp -t input.XXXXXX) || exit
trap '$'\'rm -f "$tempfile"\''' EXIT
printf "%s\n" "$2" >"$tempfile" || exit
set -- "$1" "$tempfile"
'

ssh_args=( -o ConnectTimeout=5 -i ./private_key )
while IFS= read -r line <&3; do 
    printf -v args_q '%q ' "$1" "$(<"$2")"
    if ! ssh "${ssh_args[@]}" "as@$line" "bash -s $args_q" \
            < <(printf '%s\n' "$script_prefix"; cat mod_users.sh); then
        echo "Operation failed for $line" >&2 
    fi
done 3<"$3"
```